# MongooseServerSelectionError for what?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const Campground = require('./models/campground');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelp-camp", () => {
    console.log("database connected");
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error!!!:'));

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/make_campground', async (req, res) => {
    const camp = new Campground({title: 'My Backyard', description: 'cheap camping!'});
    await camp.save().then(() => console.log("Camp saved"));
    res.send(camp);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serving on port 3000')
})
```

I searched for this problem for one day, but couldn't find any solution.

There is an error after database connected.

restarting mongodb wasn't solution.

please help me...

this is screenshot of cmd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfM2k.png)